# Not show image thumbnail with like button facebook in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I would like to ask all of you one question.
I have integrate Facebook button like in my web using cakephp.
When I click button like it show popup without image thumbnail it show only description.
I copy my url to debug in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/
It show message error like below:
[image]